# CouchDB in NestJS

Tags: typescript, couchdb, nestjs

I am getting started with NestJs and CouchDB. I am looking for a tutorial to get started but I can't find anything specific to CouchDB for NestJS. For nodejs I am finding quite a lot of stuff, but nothing about nestjs.
I am new in both, NestJS and CouchDB, and to begin with, I can't find any library or package to use CouchDB in NestJS-

Does anyone know any tutorial on how to get started or just tell me here how to get started. How to connect CouchDB to NestJS and how to get the stuff from CouchDB to NestJS.

Thank you.

Comment: Requests for resources, such as books, tools, libraries, or tutorials, are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate best bet would be to create a [Dynamic Module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) that's a simple wrapper around CouchDB. It doesn't have to be anything as fancy as the Nest packages for Mongo, Sequelize, or TypeORM. [I have a decent example of a Postgres wrapper](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/master/apps/api/src/app/database) if you wannna take a look at that.

Otherwise, [this is a great article on dynamic modules](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370)

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB need not require a library since it has APIs for interaction. You can invoke APIs to perform CRUD operation on your CouchDB database with any programming language. The official link for CouchDB APIs is
https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/index.html